# ¿Dónde pongo el codigo para poder usar findByView, AndroidStudio?

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.proyectotabl;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link Fragmento3#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class Fragmento3 extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;



    Button agregar;
    EditText signo_nuevo;
    TextView lista_signos;
    String lista;
    String tn;



    public Fragmento3() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment Fragmento3.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static Fragmento3 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Fragmento3 fragment = new Fragmento3();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        agregar=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        signo_nuevo=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSignos);
        lista_signos=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLista);



        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }



    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment



        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragmento3, container, false);


    }
}
```

Soy nuevo programando en androidstudio y acabo de hacer una app con 3 fragmentos, cada uno con su archivo java y su archivo xml con un tab layout, ademas de los 2 archivos respectivos de main con viewpager2 para pasar entre estas 3 paginas, puse unos campo de texto, un boton y un espacio de texto en el tercer fragmento pero no se donde poner su cogido para que funcione, va en mainactivity? o en el java de dicho fragmento, incluyo codigo donde intente comenzar a poner el codigo en el 3° fragmento pero si lo pongo ahi no detecta la funcion findViewById y si pongo el codigo en mainactivity no encuentra las id de los botones o campos, ayuda porfavor

Comment: Los elementos que vas a buscar están en el layout, por tanto debes buscarlos una vez el mismo se haya cargado. Para el caso del Fragment debería ser en `onCreateView`. Dicho eso, Android tiene una mejor forma para cargar los elementos. Cuando puedas lee sobre **Vinculación de Vista**.

Answer (score 0):

El problema se debe a que no estás definiendo el layout desde el cual se obtendrán las referencias de las vistas mediante `findViewById()`, para definir un layout lo debes realizar mediante el método [setContentView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setContentView(int)).

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //* No estas usando setContentView() para cargar un layout!


        agregar=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        signo_nuevo=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSignos);
        lista_signos=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLista);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }



    }
```

Debes asegurar que en el layout que cargas tengas las vistas con los ids de los cuales tratas de obtener las referencias, en este caso sería `btnAdd`, `etSignos`, `txtLista`

Suponiendo que tu layout se llama `activity_main.xml`, en realidad deberías tener algo similar a:

```
  @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
     
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  //*Carga layout que contiene las vistas.
     
           agregar=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
            signo_nuevo=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSignos);
            lista_signos=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLista);
    
            if (getArguments() != null) {
                mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
                mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
            }
    }
```